# Возможна ли передача голоса по Jabber протоколам?

Tags: c#, xmpp

Возможна ли передача голоса по Jabber протоколам в принципе?
Если да, то с помощью каких библиотек?

Comment: @Pavel Crystal, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Быстрый поиск по stakoverflow говорит, что можно.
Возможно, поможет:

[libjingle](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/)

[Jingle](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html#howitworks)